# Facing issue in composer installation (EE version)

Tags: magento2, installation, composer

[image]

facing issue on composer install for EE version. any solution?

Is there any way to change the Magento repo credential from the composer? I have configured one & save it in composer, I need to re-configure the second one.

Comment: It’s the issue with auth keys. Try different one.

Comment: @Sudhanshu Bajaj yes but that key working in another system nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Magento Key has been expired for EE version need to change.